# Manually update GKE autopilot version in GCP?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine

I have a GKE autopilot cluster which was initially configured to use `STABLE` updates channel. It is using version `1.18.20-gke.900` of Kubernetes engine right now.

However, I need a minimum version of `1.19` to use the ingress feature.

I can see that `STABLE` channel supports the following versions:

- `1.19.12-gke.2100`
- `1.19.11-gke.2101`
- `1.18.20-gke.900`

With `1.18.20-gke.900` being the default.

However, I don't see an option in the console to actually perform an upgrade from currently running `1.18.20-gke.900` to e.g. `1.19.11-gke.2101`. Is it possible?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you can't do this through the console.

However, you can manually upgrade the control plane of a cluster using the [gcloud CLI utility](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud) this way:

```bash
gcloud container clusters upgrade \
  "${CLUSTER_NAME}" \
  --master \
  --cluster-version "${NEW_VERSION}" \
  [--region "${REGION}"]
```

**Example:**

```bash
gcloud container clusters upgrade "control" \
  --master \
  --cluster-version "1.19.12-gke.2100" \
  --region europe-west3
```

Be aware that this will take significant amount of time.

After the control is updated you can also update the nodes to the same version:

```bash
gcloud container clusters upgrade \
  "${CLUSTER_NAME}" \
  [--region "${REGION}"]
```

You can read more in the dedicated article:
[Manually upgrading a cluster or node pool](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/upgrading-a-cluster)

Comment: In general, the `--cluster-version` flag is optional for `gcloud container clusters upgrade`. If left out, it will update to the latest in the channel.

Comment: Node upgrade doesn't work on autopilot clusters with error: 
`ERROR: (gcloud.container.clusters.upgrade) ResponseError: code=400, message=Autopilot clusters do not support mutating node pools.`